# How to save multiple values from same input names

Tags: php, sql, forms, mysqli

How would I save in multiple rows values from same input names.

For example, my php,html code from is:

```
<form action="functions.php" method="post" name="grades">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php $unos = $baza->odradi("SELECT subject FROM subjects ORDER BY id ASC"); 
            if (!empty($unos)) { 
                foreach($unos as $row=>$value){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="subject_id[]" value="<?= $unos[$row]["id"]; ?>"> <?= $unos[$row]["subject"]; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control input-xs" name="grade_id[]" required>
                                <option selected disabled>Select grade</option>
                                <option value="5">excelent</option>
                                <option value="4">very good</option>
                                <option value="3">good</option>
                                <option value="2">ok</option>
                                <option value="1">bad</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="grades" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit grades">
</form>
```

And function which from where it needs to be saved looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['grades'])) {  
    foreach (array_combine($_POST['subject_id'], $_POST['grade_id']) as $i => $val){
        $subject = $_POST["subject_id"][$i];
        $grade = $_POST["grade_id"][$i];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO final_grade (subject_id,grade_id) VALUES ('$subject','$grade')";
        $u = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    }
```

But it's all messed up,in first two rows there is no grade or subject saved, and all some rows are missing completely.

Comment: You don't need to `combine()`.  Just use one of the input array to set up the loop, then use `$i` when accessing the other array inside the loop.  And you NEED prepared statements for security/stability.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling `array_combine()`, your loop is not passing the subarray indexes as `$i` anymore.  It is passing the `subject_id` as `$i` and `grade_id` as `$val`.  You could have just used `$i` and `$val` as the values to insert rather than trying to re-access the `$_POST` arrays with `$i`.

Cleaner scripting would be to use the ids as hardcoded element keys on each `<select>` instead of passing a hidden field.

```
<?php
$options = [
    5 => 'excellent',
    4 => 'very good',
    3 => 'good',
    2 => 'ok',
    1 => 'bad'
];
?>

<td><?= $unos[$row]["subject"]; ?></td>
<td><select class="form-control input-xs" name="grade[<?= $unos[$row]["id"]; ?>]" required>
    <option disabled>Select grade</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($options as $opt_id => $opt_val) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$opt_id}\">{$opt_val}</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
 </td>
```

Then you can simply access the associative submission.

```
if (isset($_POST['grade'])) {  
    // use prepared statement and bind variables
    foreach ($_POST['grade'] as $id => $val) {
        // execute prepared statement with each iteration
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could build up a single batch of results and do a single INSERT (I'd probably do it this way).

Suggested batch insert code:

```
$placeholders = [];
$params = [''];  // instantiate with no types in first element
foreach ($_POST['grade'] as $subject_id => $grade_id) {
    $placeholders[] = '(?,?)';  // all necessary placeholders for the row
    $params[0] .= 'ii'; // because you are passing 2 integer values per batch
    array_push($params, $subject_id, $grade_id);
}

// execute single batch of inserts
$query = "INSERT INTO final_grade (subject_id,grade_id) VALUES " . implode(',', $placeholders);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bind_param($params);
$stmt->execute();
```

The truth is, there are a number of ways that you can pass the data from your form and a number of ways that you can execute the INSERT query.  I won't bother to write out all of the variations -- do what you like ...but definitely write stable/secure queries.